pylint useless-parent-delegation conflicts with super-init-not-called error
I have a simple python class where I have the following init:
class Foo(Bar):

   def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

This causes pylint to complain with a useless-parent-delegation error.
When I delete the call to super(), pylint complains with a super-init-not-called error.
Feels like a no-win case. Other than suppressing the error, what is the correct fix to avoid both pylint errors?
I'm using python-3.11 .

I wasn't able to reproduce super-init-not-called until I realized the parent class needs to have an __init__. I had just done class Bar: pass. So it'd help if you added an example version of Bar. See [mre].

@wjandrea you are absolutely right. I'll build a complete example in the next couple of days. For now, I've just disabled the pylint error.

I don't think you need to override __init__ at all here if you just want Foo to have the same constructor as Bar.
class Foo(Bar):
    pass

However, since you do use **kwargs only, you prevent positional arguments from being used for Foo that would potentially be valid for Bar. I think that's an unusual case, so if that's what you intend to do, you will have to just tell pylint to ignore that line.
class Foo(Bar):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        # pylint: disable=useless-parent-delegation
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

